# How can you return a non-const reference to an element in a std::vector data member from a const member function?

Tags: c++, stdvector, member-functions, const-correctness, function-qualifier

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to return a `non-const` reference to an element in a `std::vector` from a const member function. A simple example of what I'm going for is,

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
 public:
 MyClass : myVec(3)
 {
 }

 T& x() const
 {
    return *(myVec.data())[0]
 }

 std::vector<T> myVec;
}
```

The behavior I'm going for is that I'd like to be able to do things like the following,

```
MyClass obj<double>;
obj.x() = 3.3;
assert(obj.x()==3.3)
```

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) gives the same type of behavior, but I've not been able to figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: @jlack  It is not clear why you are trying to return a non-constant reference to a constant object.

Comment: Why is `x` const?  If you have a mutating accessor it should not be const.

Comment: It is debatable whether the items within a container should be constant just because the container is. If I have a constant container of non constant pointers, is that fundamentally different? You could view the const-ness as only applying to what items are present, and not what their value is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), and it'll do the work here, (according to the usage posted). But you won't need it for this case (and for most cases).

You could (and should) add non-const member function overloading for it. Then const member function returns reference to const, non-const member function returns reference to non-const. The appropriate one will be invoked via [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions).

```
const T& x() const
{
   return myVec[0];
}
T& x()
{
   return myVec[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard library containers extend the const-ness of the container to the values themselves. Since your class is constant in `x()`, so is the vector. You could use [const_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) to remove the `const` from the item in your accessor.

```
return const_cast <T&> (*(myVec.data())[0]);
```

In general this is considered bad practice, since `const` is there to protect you. Bypassing those protections can make the code harder to reason about.